# What is $\frac{\int f(x)\, dx}{\int f(x)\, dx}$ equal to?

Tags: calculus

What is the expession 
$$ \frac{\int f(x) \,dx}{\int f(x)\, dx} \text{?}$$

From one side it seems to be $1$. For another side the integral is a  set parametrised by constant, so
$$ \frac{\int f(x)\, dx}{\int f(x) \,dx}=\frac{F(x)+C_1}{F(x)+C_2},
$$
where $F(x)$ is the antiderivarive of $f(x).$ From this point of view we get $1$  only in the case $C_1=C_2.$

So, how to simplify $$ \frac{\int f(x) \,dx}{\int f(x) \,dx} \text{?}$$

P.S. The question inspired by

[image]

Comment: Your second expression is the right answer. Antiderivatives are not unique. You cannot do any better than a general class of functions as you've written.

Comment: For that matter, what is the expression $\int 0 \; dx$? Unless you choose a specific additive constant, this is meaningless

Comment: @CameronWilliams : I'm not so sure I would say anything is the right answer to this question in the form in which it appears here.

Comment: @Michael Hardy  Please correct the form of this question

Comment: @Leox : I don't think I would ever write such an expression as this fraction unless there were some context to make it clear just what is meant.

Comment: @Michael Hardy Why do you think the question is unclear?

Comment: It's basically one, except at roots of the antiderivative of $f$ (?)

Comment: @Leox This question is ill-defined: if it does not make sense to write $\frac{\int f(x)\,dx}{\int f(x)\,dx}$, then it does not make sense to ask how to simplify the expression. A more fundamental question may be what the expression $\int f(x)\, dx$ really means.

Comment: @Leox The notation $\int f(x)\, dx$ really means a *family* of functions. It does not make sense to write a fraction of two families of functions, just like it does not make sense to ask what is $\frac{\{1,2,3,4\}}{\{\pi,e,57,0\}}$.

Comment: @Jack Well, I agree, partially

Comment: @Leox: So do you see this expression somewhere or do you make it up?

Comment: @Jack  See my correction of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a more subtle notational question here: "what exactly do we mean by $\int f(x)\ dx$?"

On the one hand, if you already *know* some function $g(x)$ and have defined $g(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$, then you could just assume that $\int f(x)\ dx=g(x)$.

On the other hand, if you consider antiderivatives in a more general light, the expression $\int f(x)\ dx$ is not even well defined (at least in terms specific functions). This issue doesn't usually come up in calculus because it isn't really relevant - you can just write $\int f(x)\ dx = F(x)+c$ and call it a day.

To clear this up, you need to define *precisely* what a derivatives and antiderivatives are:

Let $F\{\Bbb{R}\}$ denote the set of functions $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$. The derivative is the function $D:F\{\Bbb{R}\}\to F\{\Bbb{R}\}$ such that for a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$...

$$D(f)(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Then, the antiderivative is the *inverse* of $D$ - i.e. the function $D^{-1}:F\{\Bbb{R}\}\to F\{\Bbb{R}\}$ such that $D^{-1}(D(f))=f$. There's just one problem: $D$ is not invertible. This is not a new problem either; non-invertible functions appear in elementary algebra all the time - just consider all of the polynomial functions with more than one root.

And, just like with polynomial functions, there are ways around this.

The first thing you can do is select a *principle* value to define the inverse function. In the case of $f(x)=x^2$, the "inverse function" is $f^{-1}(x)=\pm\sqrt{x}$. We define the principle value of $\pm\sqrt{x}$ to be $\sqrt{x}$.

Similarly, you could select a "principle antiderivative" for each function $f$ so that the $D^{-1}(f)$ is always defined. In this case, the expression $\frac{\int f(x)\ dx}{\int f(x)\ dx}$ will always evaluate to $1$.

Alternatively, you can define the antiderivative of $f$ as the *set* of all functions whose derivative is $f$, or, in notation...

$$D^{-1}(f)=\{F:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}:D(F)=f\}$$

This is similar to defining the $\sqrt[n]{x}$ as the *set* of all values $y$ such that $y^n=x$.

In this case, the expression $\frac{\int f(x)\ dx}{\int f(x)\ dx}$ would be defined using elementwise division between the set $D^{-1}(f)(x)$ and itself. Elementwise division is defined as$^1$...

$$\frac{X}{Y}=\left\{\frac xy:x\in X\land y\in Y\right\}$$

Two things should be apparent here: 1) elementwise division between sets yields another set, not a single value 2) elementwise division may or may not produce a different set from the arguments (this latter point can easily be seen by considering $\frac{\Bbb{Z}^+}{\Bbb{Z}^+}=\Bbb{Q}^+$ and $\frac{\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}}{\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}}=\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$).

With this in mind the value of your expression depends both on the function $f$, and on domain and codomain of $f$. Although I have only discussed real-valued functions of a single real variable here, the process applies to any set of functions on which a "derivative" can be defined. For example, you could do something similar with the set of functions $\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$, $\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$, $\Bbb{H}\to\Bbb{H}$, or $\Bbb{R}^{n\times n}\to\Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (the latter two require some clarification, since multiplication is noncommutive, but the concept is the same).

$^1$ To my knowledge, there is no standard notation for elementwise division between sets. I have used $\frac XY$ here, but there may be another way to denote this. This should not be confused with the quotient set $X/Y$.

Comment: What is the password? :)

Comment: Since no conditions are given, I would assume that the integration constant is $0$. So the password is $1$.